# Make css html progress bar goes from bottom to top

Tags: html, css

Hello this might be a simple for some. But I could not find how to solve it.
I have a progress bar that uses two images, and the colored image fills the background grayscale image with the percentual value.
The code below works, but it is filling the image from top to bottom, I want to fill from bottom to top. I've tried using flexbox, switch from top 0, to bottom 0, but didn't work. Could someone give some help?

Thanks in advance.

```js
function setProgress(percent) {
  var progressBar = document.getElementById('progress');
  progressBar.style.height = percent + '%';
}
```

```css
setProgress(90);
.progress-container {
  width: 268px;
  height: 608px;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/jl6OFd6.png');
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  bottom:0;
  position: relative;
  top:0;

}

.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/Xv6WaQ5.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: height 0.2s ease-out;  

}
```

```html
<div class="progress-container">
  <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change 'background-position / position'.

```
.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/Xv6WaQ5.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: height 0.2s ease-out;  
}
```

Comment: With the background-position as bottom I have an effect like an overlay. If you could check here https://codepen.io/FeriusWolf/pen/wvEXrPz
The background-position as top, the colored imagine continues coming from the top to bottom, and the colored image comes down, not as an overlay, but as another image over the background.

Comment: chage css top:0 -> bottom:0 
https://codepen.io/2ju2/pen/QWVxaGX
like this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this !!!

In html:

```
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
```

In your CSS

```
.progress-bar {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.progress {
  background-color: #007bff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).